# Ошибка при вводе команды input

Tags: python, input

вот код, работаю на VS code:

```
name= input()
print('hello', name)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
your name
>>> bob
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bob' is not defined
```

В похожих вопросах часто отвечают что установлен python 2, но у меня на данный момент версия 3.12.2

Comment: Так вы код не туда вводите. Его надо не в интерпретатор, а в отдельный файл вставлять, и тогда уже запускать.

Comment: Почти наверняка используется второй питон. Выведи версию питона внутри программы.

Answer (score -1):

Код рабочий, проверь в нормальном ide [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).